# How to find the short run and long run cost functions, given the production function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

> The production function of car is given by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}$ (assume competitive input and output markets).
>
> 1. Find the short run cost function (let input 3 be ﬁxed in short run) and the long run cost function.
> 2. Derive the proﬁt function, supply function and input demand functions.

I was able to find the short run cost function but I'm having trouble evaluating the long run cost function and part 2 of the question.

I don't know how to approach such questions as I am new to the field of economics.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please [edit] your question to include your thoughts and efforts, explaining what you've tried and what you're having trouble with. This will help people know exactly what you need help with, and write answers that actually address your problem.

Comment: Isn't the long-run cost function just the solution to $\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3} p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3$ s.t. $\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3} = q$? Is it the algebra of solving this that you have a problem with? Have you heard of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: yes,i just don't know how to proceed with the problem,what concept to apply and no i have not heard of lagrange multipliers.please help me in solving such questions in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long-run cost function is the solution to 
$\min_{x_1,x_2,x_3} p_1x_1+p_2x_2+p_3x_3$ s.t. $\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3} = q$. This type of problem is solved most easily with the help of [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) by constructing a new function that 'penalizes' violation of the constraints. We then choose a multiplier on this 'penalty' s.t. it is optimal not to violate the constraint. (Don't worry if you don't get this intuition - most undergraduates in econ use it without understanding why it works).

Thus we define $\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\lambda) = p_1x_1+p_2x_2+p_3x_3 - \lambda(\sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}-q)$ and maximize this for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ **and** $\lambda$. The FOCs are $p_1 = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{x_1}}$, $p_2 = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{x_2}}$, $p_3 = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{x_3}}$ and the constraint itself. Dividing the first by the second and rearranging yields $\frac{p_1}{p_2} \sqrt{x_1} = \sqrt{x_2}$ and similarly we can derive $\frac{p_1}{p_3} \sqrt{x_1} = \sqrt{x_3}$. Plugging this into the constraint yields:

$\begin{eqnarray*}\sqrt{x_1}+\frac{p_1}{p_2}\sqrt{x_1}+\frac{p_1}{p_3} \sqrt{x_1} &=& q, \\ \text{ i.e. } x_1 &=& \left(\frac{q}{\frac{p_1}{p_1}+\frac{p_1}{p_2}+\frac{p_1}{p_3}}\right)^2.\end{eqnarray*}$

You can repeat this to yield solutions for $x_2$ and $x_3$ -- or you could recognize the symmetry. The cost function is then just $C(q) = p_1x_1(q)+p_2x_2(q)+p_3x_3(q)$.

The profit function is $\pi(q) =  pq-C(q)$ (assuming the firm is competitive) and the supply function is just the  $q$ that solves $\max_q \pi(q)$. The input demand functions are the functions we already computed above, i.e. $x_1(q)$ etc.

Hope this helps. If not please specify what level of education you are currently in - in particular I am surprised somebody asked you to solve this without telling you about Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: thank you so much leon..that was helpful..could you please refer to me a good book for microeconomics through which i can strengthen my basics in micro and learn to handle such mathematical problems in economics.thank you

Comment: The standard non-mathematical intro is Varian "Intermediate Microeconomics". If you are at graduate school or preparing for it, Mas-Colell et al "Microeconomic Theory". But both of those don't *really* cover the maths - any standard Calculus book should help you with that. I've seen Simon Blume "Mathematics for Economists" recommended, but it's sth you would look at after a Calculus course

Comment: well i have studied mathematics during my graduation so i'm ok with any level of calculus.but i'm new to the field of economics in which i hope to pursue a masters next year.i have read varian but i found the text too plain to be of much help when tackling mathematical problems such as the one above.thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah fair. Definitely Mas-Colell and perhaps Simon/Blume then. If you find Mas-Colell to dense, you could also look at Kreps "A Course in Microeconomic Theory".